# Timeout in resolve function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to wrap my resolve function in a timeout. I keep getting an error saying `Unexpected token function`

Can anyone see my syntax error?

Thanks!

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $timeout) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm',
            resolve: {

                $timeout(function() {
                    myList: function(List) {
                        return List.getMyList();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        })
```

Comment: If it's a syntax error, do you not see something in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `$timeout` promise and then after `$timeout` resolves you could call `List.getMyList()` which returns a `data`/`promise`(depends on `getMyList` method implementation).

**Code**

```
resolve: {
     myList: function(List) {
         return $timeout(function() {}, 2000).then(function(){
            return List.getMyList();
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: @Grundy isn't that correct..? returning `List.getMyList()` after 2 seconds

Comment: yep, now seems ok, but of course OP need check it :-)